# Word that describes a dramatic device that disrupts equilibrium

Tags: single-word-requests, literary-english

I am seeking a word, should it indeed exist, that describes a dramatic or literary device found when a new character is introduced into a story which disrupts the natural equilibrium, driving the story.

For example, in J. B. Priestley's *An Inspector Calls*, there is a natural equilibrium at the Birlings' home. This exists, however, until the Inspector arrives - disrupting the natural order, it seems, and goes on to defining the narrative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the opposite of deus ex machina: **[diabolus ex machina](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeusExMachina)**

> Diabolus ex Machina (Demon from the Machine) is the Evil Counterpart of Deus ex Machina: the introduction of an unexpected new event, character, ability, or object designed to ensure that things suddenly get much worse for the protagonists, much better for the villains, or both.

Though it is not a well-established term like deus ex machina. These kind of events can be interpreted as "**[plot twist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot_twist)**" as well.

> A plot twist is **a radical change in the expected direction or outcome** of the plot of a novel, film, television series, comic, video game, or other work of narrative.

Comment: It doesn't have much currency outside of tvtropes, but here's [diabolus ex machina](http://www.itsfilm.com/screenwriting-terminology/) defined as *Arbitrary, unjustifified obstacle for the protagonist.* Which doesn't really quite seem to fit the bill in OP's context, where the protagonist (the Inspector) actually ***is*** the "disruptive plot twist" (without which presumably there would be no story to tell).

Answer (score 0):

In the world of Literary Criticism, the standard term is...

> [**deus ex machina**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deus%20ex%20machina) (literally, "the god in the machine")
>   *A person or thing (as in fiction or drama) that appears or is introduced suddenly and unexpectedly and provides a contrived solution to an apparently insoluble difficulty*.

Comment: "contrived solution" - I am looking for the opposite almost, in that, at present, there is no solution, but only chaos. Thanks though :)

Comment: @falcontoast: Well, in your example I suppose we could say the "apparently insoluble difficulty" is the author's problem in coming up with some way to make an interesting story (we'd soon get bored if all he had to write about was *"the natural equilibrium at the Birlings' home!"* :)

Comment: What the OP wanted was a name for something that counts as a plot development. A *deus ex machina* is not a plot development but a plot solution, and not a very convincing one. It's what writers resort to when they've run out of ideas on how to wind up the story. The arrival of the inspector in Priestley's play is what sparks off the drama, not what resolves it.

Comment: We were presented with the term [startle set](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CvJiX1dTzJQC&pg=PA308&lpg=PA308&dq=%22startle+set%22&source=bl&ots=5OTm492TAL&sig=4psrwJg3wUJyWzIy-9JRyvKIE9c&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qBIvU9nKAaSh7AaI2oDABg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22startle%20set%22&f=false) in teacher training, but it doesn't seem to be in common use.

Comment: In Lit Crit terms what we have here is simply *antithesis* (a contrast between one thing/setting/character and another). Specifically, [*In the play a **protagonist** and **antagonist** are presented. The protagonist is the Inspector, meaning that he the main character and is most perceived to be a hero as is a more prominent figure in the play. The antagonist (which is the complete opposite of protagonist) is Birling*](http://englishrevisionnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/notes-on-inspector-calls.html). But I can't really see there being a name for the "device" of *creating a story*.