# What is a word for a character who incites the conflict in a plot?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

I realize you can use 'antagonist' but I'd prefer a stronger word with virtually the same meaning. I want to use it to describe Nils Krogstad of *A Dollhouse.*

Comment: Stronger? Aside from not being sure a stronger word would be useful generally (*villain* is stronger, but less specific and with more one-dimensional overtones) if anything makes Nils not a classic antagonist its the argument that there is a sense that he could be better than he is, and he too is a victim.

Comment: It's not one word, but you could say the character _drives the plot._

Comment: Related: [Word that describes a dramatic device that disrupts equilibrium](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159368/word-that-describes-a-dramatic-device-that-disrupts-equilibrium/159385#159385)

Comment: Having not seen the show/anime you mentioned but if you are looking for a negative term ''Rebel" seems to fit and positive term I suggest you use 'Revolutionary'. They both are the ones who incite big conflicts/wars and I guess are stronger than antagonists.

Answer (score 13):

Northrop Frye, in *The Anatomy of Criticism* (1957), introduced the term "blocking character" for the character who prevents the hero of a comedy from realizing his goal—typically marriage to the heroine—and associated the role with the *alazon* or 'braggart' of the Tractatus Coslinianus. This analysis enjoyed considerable popularity in the 60s and 70s and appears still to be widely taught.

Under the conventions within which Ibsen operated Krogstad is indeed the overt blocking character, the impediment to Nora and Torvald's marriage. But of course Ibsen is working to subvert the comic conventions of his day; and in the third act he effects an ironically inverted *anagnorosis*, a climactic transition from ignorance to understanding, in which Krogstad is revealed to be in fact the classical *eiron*, the 'self-deprecator' who contrives the stratagems which effect the 'happy' ending, and Torvald himself is revealed to be the actual blocking character and braggart.

Comment: Oh well done; that does indeed work better than *antagonist* for Nils.

Answer (score 7):

Try [**instigator:**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/instigator)

> A person who brings about or initiates something:
>
> EXAMPLE SENTENCES
>
> *he was not the **instigator** of the incident*
>
> *any **instigators** of violence will be punished*
>
> *The grizzled man is the **instigator** of all the troubles between Billy and the master-at-arms.*
>
> *The author thus implies that the means to understanding the causes of the violence and the motivations of its **instigators** lie in the study of the previous fourteen centuries.*
>
> *Can architects become **instigators** of greater disaster-response collaboration?*

(Definition and examples from Oxforddictionaries.com)

Answer (score 6):

If you need to go stronger than *antagonist*, you could always try

> **nemesis** *n*  ...
>   3. An opponent that cannot be beaten or overcome.
>   4. One that inflicts retribution or vengeance.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nemesis)

Comment: I +1ed, but I believe you should point out that a nemesis is strongly tied to another character, i.e. you have to be a nemesis *of someone*. So you would be talking about the nemesis *of the main character* (or another character, I suppose), not the nemesis of the story.

Comment: @starsplusplus: Thanks. I believe the question specifies "character" in the title, and refers specifically to a character in the body, so I thought that was explicit enough. Also, you can't really have an antagonist without having a character who is the protagonist, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Catalyst.

> Someone or something that encourages progress or change.
>
> > *Economic development and integration are working as a catalyst for peace.*

[(wiktionary)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catalyst)

It describes an agent of change, which doesn't necessarily imply conflict. But it also describes certain chemical reactions -- that could give the overtone of strength you're looking for, depending on context.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion - a catalyst is *the* word to describe "a character who incites the conflict in a plot" (or, for that matter, not necessarily a character - an object or even an abstract concept can also be a catalyst for the plot). Antagonist refers to someone who intentionally tries to ruin the plans of the main character, whereas a catalyst just describes someone (or something) who *does*, whether or not they meant to or even realized that they had. :)

Answer (score 3):

A strong word to use could be adversary.

Adversary:

> one's opponent in a contest, conflict, or dispute.

Answer (score 0):

*Miscreant, evildoer* and *villain* are all valid suggestions – but these may not fit your needs perfectly.

You could also describe him in terms of his crime:

> The mass murderer
>
> The robber

Answer (score 0):

Provocateur might fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the character, and where you are using it, it is often useful to prototypically adjectify him/her rather than use a simple noun.

By this I mean, use a prototypical character, such as Hercules, Machievelli, etc. and describe the character thus: A machiavellian anti-hero, A herculean adversary.

BUT, I would seriously re-consider your first choice. "Antagonist" in it's classic sense as an opossing force/rival (a constant struggle against) is a perfect fit as far as I can see, and there is no stronger word in this context. I strongly prefer it to 'blocking character' which whilst may convey accurately the character in the context of plot alone is overall reductive of the word antagonist in my personal opinion.

The only time I personally would use 'blocking' to describe a character would be when the blocking is either incidental to the characters primary objectives, the conflict is entirely unintentional, or when it is a comic device only.